# Better way to import multiple classes from multiple files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I made a process scheduler simulator. I gave each scheduling algorithm its' own class within its' own file. all within a folder called Schedulers. In order to use them I have to import them like this:

```
from Schedulers.SchedulerFCFS import SchedulerFCFS
from Schedulers.SchedulerSJF import SchedulerSJF
from Schedulers.SchedulerRR import SchedulerRR
```

Anytime I add a new Scheduler class I'd have to add it to the imports. 
Is there a better way to import all of these classes?

Comment: Close enough I can tweak the chosen answer to solve my problem